# How to pass data without Segue to next viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a third party SDK where it entails a viewController on it own.

So, what i do is that i just call.

```
PHViewController *vc = [[PHViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to go to the viewController.

However, i do need to pass some data to this PHViewController. How do i do that? Because if i have storyboard, i have prepareForSegue and perFormSegueWithIdentifier functions to pass data to the next viewController, but in this i don't have that.

Comment: what is data? a simple string? an image ?

Comment: Does the `PHViewController` have properties that you can set?  ...or some method to call that accepts data?

Comment: Yes data like image and textField data. @PhillipMills: nope.. Oh, so if i can create the function by editing the original SDK files! Thanks!

Comment: If `PHViewController` does have properties which can be set then you can set your data once you have initialized it. Something like : `[vc setCustomData:myData]` If you can provide a link to 3rd party SDK also it would be useful. This is tagged as `swift` but you have written Obj-C code ?

Comment: You need to have properties set on your PHViewController. Read about setter and getter methods in swift!!!

Comment: Thanks! I will try to see if i can edit the SDK files. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Without Storyboard:

```
[DestinationViewController *vc = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];
vc.myData = toBePassedData
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

With Storyboard:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? DestinationViewController else {
        return
    }
    destVC.myData = self.toBePassedData
}
```

Above is in Swift for storyboard, but you will understand the meaning.